# Deriving components of Riemann Tensor

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors

Short question that could potentially be answered without reading all the details:

Is ${\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}{A^\sigma}_{,\nu}={\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}{A^\sigma}_{,\rho}$? If so, why? If not, what has gone wrong with the following derivation?

Motivation for this question: I'm reading a text that derives the components of the Riemann tensor by examining the second covariant derivative of a vector. The first covariant derivative is defined as

\begin{equation}
D_\nu A^\mu\equiv\partial_\nu A^\mu+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\rho\nu}A^\rho
\end{equation}

and the second covariant derivative is worked out to be

\begin{equation}
D_\rho(D_\nu A^\mu)=({A^\mu}_{,\nu}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}A^\sigma)_{,\rho}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}({A^\sigma}_{,\nu}+{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\tau\nu}A^\tau)-{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\nu\rho}({A^\mu}_{,\sigma}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\tau\sigma}A^\tau)
\end{equation}

The author then skips a few steps and arrives that the result that

\begin{equation}
(D_\rho D_\nu -D_\nu D_\rho)A^\mu={R^\mu}_{\nu\tau\rho}A^\tau
\end{equation}

where ${R^\mu}_{\nu\tau\rho}$ are the components of the Riemann tensor:

\begin{equation}
{R^\mu}_{\nu\tau\rho}\equiv \partial_\rho {\Gamma^\mu}_{\nu\tau} - \partial_\nu {\Gamma^\mu}_{\rho\tau} +{\Gamma^\mu}_{\rho\sigma}{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\nu\tau}-{\Gamma^\mu}_{\nu\sigma}{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\rho\tau}
\end{equation}

I am trying to fill in the steps to verify the expression for ${R^\mu}_{\nu\tau\rho}$. This is what I have so far:

\begin{align}
(D_\rho D_\nu -D_\nu D_\rho)A^\mu &=[({A^\mu}_{,\nu}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}A^\sigma)_{,\rho}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}({A^\sigma}_{,\nu}+{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\tau\nu}A^\tau)-{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\nu\rho}({A^\mu}_{,\sigma}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\tau\sigma}A^\tau)]-
[({A^\mu}_{,\rho}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}A^\sigma)_{,\nu}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}({A^\sigma}_{,\rho}+{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\tau\rho}A^\tau)-{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\rho\nu}({A^\mu}_{,\sigma}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\tau\sigma}A^\tau)]\\
&=[\color{blue}{{A^\mu}_{,\nu,\rho}}+\partial_\rho({\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}A^\sigma)+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}{A^\sigma}_{,\nu}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\tau\nu}A^\tau- \color{red}{{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\nu\rho}{A^\mu}_{,\sigma}}-\color{green}{{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\nu\rho}{\Gamma^\mu}_{\tau\sigma}A^\tau}]
-[\color{blue}{{A^\mu}_{,\rho,\nu}}+\partial_\nu({\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}A^\sigma)+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}{A^\sigma}_{,\rho}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\tau\rho}A^\tau- \color{red}{{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\rho\nu}{A^\mu}_{,\sigma}}-\color{green}{{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\rho\nu}{\Gamma^\mu}_{\tau\sigma}A^\tau}]
\end{align}

Now, some things cancel because we're allowed to exchange the order on second partial derivatives. I've colored the pairs that I think cancel this way.

Everything here matches the expression for ${R^\mu}_{\nu\tau\rho}$ except for the two terms ${\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}{A^\sigma}_{,\nu}$ and ${\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}{A^\sigma}_{,\rho}$. If these terms are equal, then they cancel and we are done. Are they equal? If so, why? If not, can you see what I have done wrong?

Comment: If you expand out $\partial_\nu({\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}A^\sigma)$ (and the other similar term) using the product rule then you should get some more cancellations.

Comment: Ah I see, I was mentally un-distributing the $A^\sigma$ and ignoring the partials! Thanks! I have typed this up and added it as an answer. I'm not sure if there's a way to credit you in that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anthony pointed out, I did not yet apply the product rule to some of my terms:

\begin{align}
(D_\rho D_\nu -D_\nu D_\rho)A^\mu &=[\color{blue}{{A^\mu}_{,\nu,\rho}}+\partial_\rho({\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}A^\sigma)+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}{A^\sigma}_{,\nu}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\tau\nu}A^\tau- \color{red}{{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\nu\rho}{A^\mu}_{,\sigma}}-\color{green}{{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\nu\rho}{\Gamma^\mu}_{\tau\sigma}A^\tau}]
-[\color{blue}{{A^\mu}_{,\rho,\nu}}+\partial_\nu({\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}A^\sigma)+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}{A^\sigma}_{,\rho}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\tau\rho}A^\tau- \color{red}{{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\rho\nu}{A^\mu}_{,\sigma}}-\color{green}{{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\rho\nu}{\Gamma^\mu}_{\tau\sigma}A^\tau}]\\
&=[\partial_\rho({\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}A^\sigma)+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}{A^\sigma}_{,\nu}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\tau\nu}A^\tau]
-[\partial_\nu({\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}A^\sigma)+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}{A^\sigma}_{,\rho}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\tau\rho}A^\tau]\\
&=[{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu,\rho}A^\sigma+\color{orange}{{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}{A^\sigma}_{,\rho}}+\color{purple}{{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}{A^\sigma}_{,\nu}}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\tau\nu}A^\tau]
-[{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho,\nu}A^\sigma+\color{purple}{{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}{A^\sigma}_{,\nu}}+\color{orange}{{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}{A^\sigma}_{,\rho}}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\tau\rho}A^\tau]\\
&={\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu,\rho}A^\sigma+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\tau\nu}A^\tau
-{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho,\nu}A^\sigma-{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\tau\rho}A^\tau\\
&=({\Gamma^\mu}_{\tau\nu,\rho}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\rho}{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\tau\nu}
-{\Gamma^\mu}_{\tau\rho,\nu}-{\Gamma^\mu}_{\sigma\nu}{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\tau\rho})A^\tau\\
&=(\partial_\rho{\Gamma^\mu}_{\nu\tau}-\partial_\nu{\Gamma^\mu}_{\rho\tau}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\rho\sigma}{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\nu\tau}-{\Gamma^\mu}_{\nu\sigma}{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\rho\tau})A^\tau
\end{align}

as desired.